# kustomize: Strategic Merge using Argo Rollout CRD

Tags: kustomize, argocd

I'm in the process of converting some of my kustomize code to use Argo CRD `Rollout` kind (https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/) from `Deployment` kind.  The big reason is the ability to easily do Blue/Green and Canary deployments. However my problem is kustomize doesn't know about Argo `Rollout` kind.  So any type of strategic merges fails and I use strategic merges quite a bit. From my research, I believe I need to register a custom transformer, but I'm not sure how it all fits together.  So far, I came across this: https://github.com/keleustes/kustomize/blob/airshipctl/kustomize/register/RolloutCRDRegister.go  But I'm unclear how to proceed.  I did come across another project that seem to be doing something similar.  See: https://github.com/viaduct-ai/kustomize-sops#argo-cd-integration-

Has anyone worked with CRD with kustomize and could provide a little bit of help?

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few github issues regarding this similar limitation. Here's the one I was following: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1510

The best thing to do in the interim is to fork the kustomize code. The repo I'm using that supports the Argo Rollout is https://github.com/keleustes/kustomize.  Not the best situation, but I'm confident this feature will be added in the coming months.